# How to enter values to group of textfields in a table using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to enter values to a group of text fields using selenium in a table as shown below.
[image]

I tried in this way but it didn't work and raise an `InvalidElementStateException`.

```
 List<WebElement> marks = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr/td/input"));
    for (WebElement mark : marks) {
    mark.sendKeys("10");
    }
```

**EDIT :
In my html, the td contains an extra hidden inputs also.**

```
<tbody>
<tr class="text-center student-mark" id="1">
    <td class="text-left">Name</td>

    <td class="activityTableBody hidden" >
        <input type="text" class="table-input 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_classTest" 
               id="55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_classTest_556da05c699e70287ca203b0_classTest" value="0">
    </td>

    <td class="activityTableBody" >
        <input type="text" class="table-input 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity1" 
               id="55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity1_556da05c699e70287ca203b0_Task-1" value="0">
    </td>

    <td class="activityTableBody" >
        <input type="text" class="table-input 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity2" 
               id="55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity2_556da05c699e70287ca203b0_Task-1" value="0">
    </td>

    <td class="activityTableBody">
        <input type="text" class="table-input 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity3" 
               id="55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity3_556da05c699e70287ca203b0_Task-1" value="0">
    </td>

    <td class="activityTableBody" >
        <input type="text" class="table-input 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity4" 
               id="55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity4_556da05c699e70287ca203b0_Task-1" value="0">
    </td>

    <td class="activityTableBody" >
        <input type="text" class="table-input 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity5" 
               id="55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_activity5_556da05c699e70287ca203b0_Task-1" value="0">
    </td>

    <td class="tableBodySA hidden" >
        <input type="text" class="table-input 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_markSA"   value="0">
    </td>
    <td class="tableBodySA hidden" *emphasized text*>
        <input type="text" class="table-input saMark 55630af2a0c4655a1ce06fcd_markSA100" width="20%"  value="0">
    </td>

</tr>
.
.
</tbody>
```

Comment: please share your HTML code .. please decribe more in which coloum do you want to enter day .. in all coloumns?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Actually I want to enter the value in all text fields in the table, not a specific column.

Comment: your code seems fine.. there must a problem with your locator.. Thats why I asked for the HTML code...

Comment: before sendkeys, u have to click on that element..some times u need to clear it... give details of ur html part.

Comment: I tried to click and clear but not worked.

Comment: @ShubhamJain I tested the locator using fire path in firefox and it selects all the text fields in table correctly.

Comment: @azhar:  if possible, can you share url, I can give a try.

Comment: Actually, when the page loads the table is hidden after clicking a button the table is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the `input` in a `td` which does not have class 'hidden'

```
List<WebElement> marks = driver.findElements(By.xpath(
                ".//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class ,'activityTableBody' ) and not(contains (@class ,'hidden'))]/input"));
        for (WebElement mark : marks) {
            Integer studentMark = i++ % 6;
            System.out.println(studentMark);
            mark.click();
            mark.sendKeys(Integer.toString(studentMark));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This working example (from the HTML you provied) fills all the visible cells :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://fiddle.jshell.net/40vr7top/show");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);

List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.activityTableBody input"));
for (WebElement input : inputs) {
  input.clear();
  input.sendKeys("99");
}
```

Comment: You should provide the page source or a reproducible example. There's not enough information to provide an answer that will work right away.

Comment: i tried ur solution in my application but i got an error `.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated`

Comment: I asked for the page source or a reproducible example and you only provided a partial HTML. So again there is not enough information here to understand the underlying behaviour.